# How to put the background color and opacity for a div block?

Tags: jquery, html

i want to put the background color and opacity for a two div blocks, hi i already put my code in html javascript file, can anyone tell me the how to put through j query code. using my div block id "**result2 how to put the background color and opacity for a div block by using the jquery"**
my div block code is, and my jquery code is, but it not coming for 2 div blocks, tell me the
solution for this

```
$('#result2').css('background-color', '#066B12').css({ opacity: 0.2 });
$('#result3').css('background-color', '#066B12').css({ opacity: 0.2 });
<div id="result2">
    <div>
         <img src="" class="pImage" style="width:30%;height:127px;float:left">                                 
    </div>
        <div style="width:70%;float:right;color:#FFFFFF">
          <div class="name"></div>
          <div class="country"></div>
          <div class="card_content" align="center"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#result3,#result2').css({'background-color': '#066B12','opacity': '0.2'});
});
```

Comment: hi because i have to assign dynamically for that div block, so i required jquery code. its not coming

Comment: @user3433253:in that case you need to wrap the code in document ready. check the updated answer.

Comment: i use this approach for both the divs, background color is coming, but opacity(transparency) not applying

Comment: @user3433253: can you share the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery here , you can apply pure CSS instead:

```
#result2, #result3 {
    background-color: #066B12;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Since you put your DOM after your script, you need to wrap it inside DOM ready handler `$(function(){...});`. Also you can shorten your code by specifying multiple css attributes inside `{ }`:

```
$(function() {
    $('#result3,#result2').css({'background-color': '#066B12','opacity': '0.2'})
});
```

---

Try to do:

```
$(function() {
    $('#result3,#result2').attr("style", "background-color:#066B12; opacity: 0.2 !important");
});
```

Comment: hi because i have to assign dynamically for that div block, so i required jquery code.

Comment: i use this approach for both the divs, background color is coming, but opacity(transparency) not applying

Comment: hi, still the opacity is not coming properly

Comment: Please create a demo to replicate your problem so I can help you more.

Comment: hi, when i put this code in my application of java-script file        $('#result3,#result2').css({'background-color': '#066B12','opacity': '0.2'}) only the background color is coming, but opacity it not applying, in my application i applying the opacity by 20%